# Publish vs Deployment of windows application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

Is there any difference between publishing a windows application and deploy the application?

I have gone through the below site.

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx)

> msbuild /target:publish /property:BootstrapperEnabled=true

returns a folder with setup.exe

so what is the purpose of deploy it using Mage.exe

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx)

what is the difference in the result?

Comment: I believe deploy will publish the setup and install it at the same time on your machine.

Comment: So deploy and publish is one and the same? If it so what is the use of  Mage.exe?